# Duplicate all network traffic to an GCE instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is it possible to duplicate all the traffic to and from the different GCE instances and send it to one instance?
So that instance can listen to all the network traffic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a proxy instance with NAT enabled and configure IPTables in that instance accordingly to your needs. Currently this is the only way for an instance to have a look at another one's traffic, as GCE virtual network doesn't implement a shared medium a promiscuous interface can hear to. See [Configuring a NAT gateway](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#natgateway) at GCE public documentation for more details.